# How to Migrate from Liferay to SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liferay, saml-2.0, apacheds

We have a web portal with Liferay6.0.5. In this portal we have a lot of portlets, which are organized as modules. For the different customers we are "showing" different amount of this modules( the other modules are not deployed to the customer at all).
Now the decision was made that we won't use liferay anymore.
The problem is that in order to do this we need a lot of time, so we need the old portal to be running and the new one too.
We will rewrite module by module.
I would like to have any suggestions how we can do this, because I'm not so deep in the things.
Currently I'm thinking of ApacheDS. Which can be our directory service and we have to transfer in some way the user data.
SAML in order when you login into the old system you don't have to login into the new one.
One question is: is there a way the portlet of the old system to be in some way embedded in the new system? 
I need to have a menu( which is always there) and if you click "Clothes" the portlet responsiblefor this to be embedded.
I'm planning to use SpringBoot.
Every advice will be appreciated, because currently I don't know how to do it.

Comment: When do you say Portlets in 6.0.5 what was used to develop them? Plain JSR or did you use spring portlets. What characters do the portlets have? Do they make sans by them self or do dey require interaction? What do you plan to you in the new system besides spring boot? What did you use form Liferay? Page structure? Permissions? What is the primary reason to move away from Liferay?

Comment: I think that they are JSR. The models doesn't depend on each other. They are using some data, but it is taken from the database, so  we can deploy the modules independently from the others. We are using the login from liferay, permissions, and I think the file storing. I don't know the primary reason why we want to move away from Liferay, but I think that because a lot of people say that it is old technology, the speed is not perfect and we don't want to depend on Liferay anymore.